# package or namespace load failure

Tags: r, forecasting

I don't know what happened but this NAMESPACE LOAD FAILURE is coming every time I call the forecast package.

***So I have used this line of code***

```
install.packages("forecast",repos = c("http://rstudio.org/_packages",
                            "http://cran.rstudio.com"))
```

***This was the console message that I got after running this code***

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/adarsh/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository 
http://rstudio.org/_packages/bin/windows/contrib/3.5:
  cannot open URL 
'http://rstudio.org/_packages/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/PACKAGES'

  There is a binary version available but the
  source version is later:
         binary source needs_compilation
forecast    8.6    8.7              TRUE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 
'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/forecast_8.6.zip' 
Content type 'application/zip' length 2345112 bytes (2.2 MB)
downloaded 2.2 MB

package ‘forecast’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
C:\Users\adarsh\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpQ58pju\downloaded_packages
```

***I checked whether this was also the case with other packages.***

```
install.packages("tseries")


Installing package into ‘C:/Users/adarsh/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  dependency ‘quadprog’ is not available
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.5/tseries_0.10-46.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 414767 bytes (405 KB)
downloaded 405 KB
package ‘tseries’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked**

**The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\adarsh\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpQ1vu1H\downloaded_packages**


    library(tseries)


Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tseries’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘quadprog’
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘tseries’ was built under R version 3.5.3
```

Same error happened again. Please anyone help me.

Comment: do you get error messages when you try `install.packages("forecast")` instead?

Comment: Have you tried `install.packages('forcast', discrepancies = T)`

Comment: @koki25ando yes i did

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the " **quadprog** " package from the **cran repository** and saved it as zip file at **C://Users/yourname/Documents/package_file.zip** .

Then used the option **Package Archive File (.zip; .tar.gz)** in R studio and installed the above package.

Thank you